# groupby datediff in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, aggregate-functions, date-difference

I am trying to get the difference between the min date and max date a product is sold in terms of month in a new column.But I am having an unusual return when apply function in groupby.

Any help is much appreciated.

So my steps are :

data :

```
    pch_date      day product  qty  unit_price  total_price  year_month  
421 2013-01-07  tuesday      p3   13        4.58        59.54           1   
141 2015-09-13   monday      p8    3        3.77        11.31           9   
249 2015-02-02   monday      p5    3        1.80         5.40           2   
826 2015-10-09  tuesday      p5    6        1.80        10.80          10   
427 2014-04-18   friday      p7    6        4.21        25.26           4
```

function definition :

```
    def diff_date(x):
       max_date = x.max()
       min_date = x.min()
       diff_month = (max_date.year - min_date.year)*12 + max_date.month +1
       return diff_month
```

When trying for test:

```
    print diff_date(prod_df['pch_date'])
```

> 49 which is correct

But Problem:

```
print prod_df[['product','pch_date']].groupby(['product']).agg({'pch_date': diff_date}).reset_index()[:5]
```

Results coming with a extra date:

```
      product                 pch_date

0      p1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000049
1     p10 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000048
2     p11 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000045
3     p12 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000049
4     p13 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000045
```

How to get the difference in integer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Groupby.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) instead which returns integers and not datetime objects.

```
df.groupby(['product'])['pch_date'].apply(diff_date).reset_index()
```

[image]

As a workaround for not letting the integer values getting converted to their DatetimeIndex values, you can change the last line of your function to `str(diff_month)` and you can continue using [`Groupby.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) as shown:

```
df.groupby(['product'])['pch_date'].agg({'pch_date': diff_date}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks Nickil - you made my day